# How can i create DVD menu with moving scene

Tags: video

I have DVD  its open menu with moving parts of movie (chapters)

each chapter keep moving like 3-5 second from movie

when i click on it , its open part of movie with length 10 min

what is the name of software can do that

Here is the screen shot of my DVD

[image]

Comment: There are a lot of different software options that can do this for you. I also recommend the two options AJ Henderson suggested. What software are you currently using? How did you get that menu? Or did you grab the screen shot from a different DVD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need DVD authoring software.  Any decent DVD authoring software should support this.  It uses video menus and chapter breakpoints to do this.

Adobe Encore (included with Premiere) does this in Adobe's product family.  DVD Studio Pro did this in Apple's product family, though it hasn't been updated since 2009.  There are also a number of over vendors who make DVD Authoring software capable of this functionality.

Comment: could you please give me name of free software do the same thing

Comment: I couldn't find any full featured open source DVD authoring package with about 20 minutes of searching.  There are a few basic ones, but most of them either have pre-made menus that you can use or are limited to static images.  DVD authoring software is pretty specialized, so it wouldn't surprise me if this is a case of "you get what you pay for."

Comment: you right sir , thank you for your help I will buy Adobe Encore i think its the best